# Move up Popup window when keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, android-activity, popup

I have an activity window (Activity pic), when I click the second button, popup window appears at the bottom (it's good, I need that) of screen (PopUp pic), when i click on the edit text field, brings up the keyboard, but it cover the popup window edit text fields (Keyboard 3).
Where is my error that the popup window does not up when the keyboard appears? Do you have any ideas?

**Screen shoots**

[Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkGyD.jpg)

[PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPgrN.jpg)

[Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ri7F.jpg)

**Pop-Up Window class**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width),(int)(height*.4));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
       
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(
         popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
/** ... **/
popup.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Then the only thing you need is a Listener for the Keyboard (or more general: For Window Height changes). This was actually easier than I thought - and it didn't require any special access like an Activity-object or similar. Even in my independent View-class which only knows the Context (which I didn't want to cast), I was able to accomplish that. Everything you need is only one View-object which has already been added to the layout.

```
final View root = this.getRootView();
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        root.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        // Calculate the difference between the original height and the new height
        int heightDiff = r.height() - root.getHeight();

        // Now update the Popup's position
        // The first value is the x-axis, which stays the same.
        // Second value is the y-axis. We still want it centered, so move it up by 50% of the height
        // change
        // The thir`enter code here`d and the fourth values are default values to keep the width/height
        popup.update(0, heightDiff / 2, -1, -1);
    }
});
```

Comment: getRootView() - What does this method do and where it is implemented?